# Use of ROCK algorithm in R for binary data

Tags: r, clustering, binary-data

I need use ROCK (RockCluster) algorithm for binary data in R. My binary data looks this:

```
objects cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4 ...
A       TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
B       TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
C       TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
D       FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
E       TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
F       TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

Now I need clasify these objects A-F to clusters. I apply this procedure https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/RockCluster#Dataset But I have several problems.

1. I import data from CSV file. `db <- read.csv(file="file.csv", header=TRUE, sep="|")` Fields are 1 (TRUE) and 0 (FALSE).
2. I convert this data: `x <- as.dummy(db[-1]`). After this step all columns in x are duplicated with 1 and 0. Why? It is correct please?
3. `rc <- rockCluster(x, n=4, debug=TRUE)`
4. `rf <- fitted(rc)` Why `fitted` and when rather use `predict(rc, x)`?
5. `table(db$objects, rf$cl)`
   After I get this output:

        `1 NA
   A   1    0
   B   1    0
   C   1    0
   D   0    1
   E   0    1
   F   0    1`

What way I can read this output? What objects are in clusters with other? What objects are the most similar please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start on some of your questions.

On question (2), yes this is correct. The function as.dummy creates boolean TRUE/FALSE vectors for each of the distinct levels in each column. Warning: I've found that as.dummy only works on factors, not strings; so make sure to convert each column in the training data to factors.

On question (4), fitted is used rather than predict since you are clustering on the entire data set rather than a sample of the data set.